# Java app Cant Retrive Data from mysql

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, easyphp

One Strange Problem.
I made an application in java using eclipse in which data is retrieved from a database but at the 2nd line it stops responding and also localhost server stops responding...

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:8080/testdb/", "root","");
```

by debugging i notice that eclipse called this exe

```
c:\program files\java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

but it doesn't respond.
apache server start but doesn't respond.
and it generate this error file
Apache error.log

```
Command line: 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\EASYPH~1.1\\Apache\\bin\\apache.exe -d C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-12.1/apache'
[Wed Oct 03 16:27:03.579034 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6776:tid 464] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5576
[Wed Oct 03 16:27:04.392034 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5576:tid 472] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Oct 03 16:27:08.094034 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7088:tid 476] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Oct 03 16:52:36.275034 2012] [mpm_winnt:warn] [pid 5576:tid 700] (OS 64)The specified network name is no longer available.  : AH00341: winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed
```

Comment: What has the Apache server to do with a JDBC connection? Do you want to connect directly to MySQL server or do that through an Apache server?

Comment: its solve by direct connection with mysql using port 3306
but in my earlier application i fetch data through apache server using port 8080..
does anyone have idea why apache server doesnt respond..

Comment: Apache server does not respond because you're connecting to it like a MySQL DB...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check to see if MySQL is listening on port 8080.  The default is 3306.  Did you set up your MySQL daemon to listen on port 8080?

Comment: Thanks
its solve by direct connection with mysql using port 3306
but in my earlier application i fetch data through apache server using port 8080..
can u give idea about how to setup mysql daemon to listen on port 8080..
i am using easyphp for starting mysql and apache server.

Comment: If MySQL listens on port 8080, then Apache can't have it, too.  I don't know what your architecture is, but I'd advise you to keep them separate.